# javascript always pushes the same object

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

Do you have any idea why this code always adds the last object?
Because I used

```
var obj = {}
```

and

```
var newBase = Object.assign({}, baseJson)
```

but code always use the same reference?

```
module.exports = (csv, baseJson) => {

var lines=csv.split("\n");

var result = [];

var headers=lines[0].split(";");
for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){
    var obj = {};
    var newBase = Object.assign({}, baseJson);
    obj["case"] = "Scenario";
    obj["request"] = newBase;
    obj["response"] = {
        responseCode: "5",
        actionCode: "0",
        approvalCode: "98765X",
    }
    var currentline=lines[i].split(";");
    var responseTags = ["responseCode", "actionCode", "approvalCode"];      
    for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){

        headers[j] = headers[j].replace('\r','');
        currentline[j] = currentline[j].replace('\r','')
        if (headers[j] == "Scenario") {
            obj["case"] = currentline[j];
        }
        else if (responseTags.indexOf(headers[j]) > -1 ){
            obj["response"][headers[j]] = currentline[j];
        }
        else {
            saveValue(obj["request"], headers[j], currentline[j]);
        }
    }
    result.push(obj);

}
```

I tried almost everything but I could not manage to create a new object. It uses the same reference. This code is in node.js.
Thank you

Comment: What does `console.log(result)` after the loop finishes show?

Comment: @ScottMarcus you are right problem is not about this part of code. Problem is in mocha. I try to use this array in a test but it uses last element always I will check it again.

Comment: @MehmetKemalBayer, move  var obj = {}; declaration  out of for loop and declare before for loop

Comment: all your base are belong to us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Javascript `var`s scoped to functions, not blocks. Effectively in your code `obj` is declared outside of the loop and it's properties mutated.

`let` should [solve the problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

```
for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){
  let obj = {};
  ...
  result.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem was about the other part of the code that calls the part I wrote above. I solved it by using let there.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.assign` may not clone inner objects and it just takes same reference, try stringify and parse it.

```
 var newBase = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(baseJson));
```

Refer to know more :  [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)